# MacOS Mojave: Command not found even though I can see the path when I echo $PATH

Tags: bash, macos, macos-mojave

I've installed a tool on my Mac (10.14 Mojave) called ovftool (it also comes installed with VMware Fusion). It lives in my applications folder under `VMware OVF Tool`

I've edited my `/etc/paths` file and for good measure did the `PATH=/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool:$PATH` along with adding it to my bash profile. Yet when I run the command `ovftool` I get the `command not found` message. Am I missing something here, is there some other way to set a PATH that I'm not aware of? This same exact path  for this same tool has worked before on my machine.

EDIT: Here is the print out from my path_helper
`PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/ovftool.app:/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/:/Applictions/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware\ OVF\ Tool:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool"; export PATH;`

Comment: Have you tried `cd`ing to the parent directory and running `ovftool` from there?

Comment: If you run: `echo $PATH` is the path "/Applications/VMware OVF Tool" in there? If you attempt to run: `ls /Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool` does it give you a listing of directories? or does it return: ls: /Applications/VMware OVF Tool: No such file or directory Also /etc/paths contains a list of directories, one directory path per line, so your edit might not work. You can use: /usr/libexec/path_helper to evaluate /etc/paths for correctness

Comment: The thing you add to the `PATH` needs to be the immediate directory which contains the binary. I'm guessing in your case it's going to look something like `/Applications/VMware OVF Tool/MacOS`

Comment: If I `ls` to the `/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool` I can see the contents of the directory like I expect. Including the ovftool app itself.

Comment: Do I need to change where my $HOME var points to? That currently is set to /users/<my_name> which contains an application folder that is not the one which contains the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can CD into the folder and run it using ./ovftool for a workaround, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The path adjustment should be something like

`export PATH=/Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH`

Also double check the name of the executable you are launching.

`ls /Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: I'll try pointing to the tool in the folder itself and see if that makes a difference, thanks.

Comment: even after updating /etc/paths wtih /Applications/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/ovftool.app the command is not found

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
export PATH=/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware\ OVF\ Tool/:$PATH
```